# how to add a variable within each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In code:

```
<% @offer2.each do |offer|%>

<% @menuName=Menu.find_by_menu_item_name(offer.menuName_get)%>

<% @line_item.each do |line_item|%>

<%@validPrice=(@menuName.price)*(offer.disAmountOrPercentage)%>
<%end%>
<%end%>
```

I am new in rails.I want to add `@validPrice += @validPrice` but it's not working inside the loop or outside the loop.So how do I get the sum of this variable.

Comment: You should use `snake_case` for method names and variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare `@validPrice= 0` on the top of the loop. So that it will not initialize repeatedly.

```
<% validPrice = 0 %>

<% @offer2.each do |offer|%>
  <% @menuName=Menu.find_by_menu_item_name(offer.menuName_get)%>
  <% @line_item.each do |line_item|%>
    <% validPrice += (@menuName.price)*(offer.disAmountOrPercentage) %> 
  <%end%> 
<%end%>
```

It will be better if you would make model method for this summations, rather to run in view pages.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<% @validPrice = 0 %> #initialized with zero

<% @offer2.each do |offer|%>  # 1st loop
 <% @menuName=Menu.find_by_menu_item_name(offer.menuName_get)%>
    <% @line_item.each do |line_item|%>  # 2nd loop
        <% @validPrice += (@menuName.price)*(offer.disAmountOrPercentage) %>
    <%end%>
 <%= @validPrice %>  # you can access and print @validprice out of 2nd loop here
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<% @offer2.each do |offer|%>
  <% @menuName=Menu.find_by_menu_item_name(offer.menuName_get)%>
  <% @line_item.each do |line_item|%>
    <%= validPrice = (@menuName.price)*(offer.disAmountOrPercentage) %> 
  <%end%> 
<%end%>
```